# Are there architectures with alignment greater than the size of machine word in the pre-32-bit era?

Tags: c, 16-bit

I'm writing a hobbyist cryptography project, and I want to ensure the data structures I define don't have padding bytes. The only assumption I've made about the environment, is that bytes are exactly 8 bits.

The structure consists of exact-width integers and pointer-sized integers, and I assume the pointer-sized integers have the same width as the machine word (for the moment, let's ignore x86-16 FAR pointers as they're 32-bit).

I've taken care to ensure that, under ILP32 and LP64 type models, the structure a) have no padding bytes and b) have sizes that're multiple of machine words. Towards making it portable on 16-bit machines, I needed to assume that no type have alignment requirement greater than the machine word size, e.g. the alignment of `uint32_t` is no stricter than that of `uint16_t` or `void *`.

The problem is, I don't know if I can make such assumption. So I'm asking: Are there pre-32-bit era ISAs with alignment requirements stricter than machine words? To limit scope creep, let's limit to ones that're supported as targets by a C compiler.

**Update (TL;DR)**

1. I only care about octet-oriented architectures, that're supported by a C compiler.
2. I've made my code portable on ILP32 and LP64 data models, I want to make it portable on SIP16 systems, so I need to know if I can make assumption as stated in the title. Also, I only care about native integral types (integers and pointers).
3. Hardware reality doesn't matter as much as what ABIs say, as hardware changes are more frequent than ABI definitions.

Comment: Can confirm that the 68000 is happy with 32-bit words aligned on 16-bit boundaries — no exception generated, no speed penalty.

Comment: But not 68020 and later -- while they can read unaligned words, the performance will suffer.

Comment: For TS: you can use `__attribute__((packed))` (for gcc) or equivalent compiler-specific definitions to avoid structures with alignment padding. And generally you can't assume that pointer-sized integers will be the largest ones: on x64-32 ABI all addresses and pointers are 32bit, while 'machine word' is 64 bit.

Comment: Plenty of weird older machines out there. Decades ago I ran an FTIR system (already old at the time) that was controlled by a computer with 24-bit words. No clue about a C compiler for it, but it seems unlikely that it would have used 16- or 32-bit integers. I just had to deal with converting the data files to something readable elsewhere. The 24 bits were for the data representation, counts per channel, and likely a tradeoff of enough counts for good statistics across a spectrum and the cost at the time of going to 32 bits.

Comment: IEEE 754 Floating-point datatypes are larger than 16-bit words, but I don’t know if any 16-bit ISA with support for floating-point has strict, compulsory alignment requirements (x86 doesn’t, optional alignment checks came later; there is however a performance penalty for misaligned FPU transfers).

Comment: @Tommy: The 68000 has a 16-bit data bus and a 32-bit incrementer/decrementer, so any 32-bit or multi-register operation will be performed using a sequence of 16-bit addresses.  A lot of graphics code for systems the Macintosh (and presumably others) were designed around this.

Comment: There's a distinction between what the ISA requires and what the C compiler gives you by default (e.g., machine can do unaligned reads, compiler knows performance better so aligns struct members automatically).  Usually there's a compiler-specific way to avoid this, but not necessarily.

Comment: @another-dave Not to mention the difference between an ISA's view and the real hardware as nothing prevents a 32 bit ISA to be implemented using 8 bit (or serial) access.

Comment: @another-dave: Yeah, so really this is a question about ABIs used by C implementations for these ISAs, e.g. `alignof(uint16_t)`.  But in ISO C, it's impossible for a type to have `alignof(T) > sizeof(T)`, otherwise arrays would have some elements with less alignment than `alignof(T)`.  So this question is weird, not clear exactly what kind of problem they're worried about, or if this comment is an answer.  (Or if any real implementations fall outside the realm of what ISO C specifies...)

Comment: @PeterCordes: It would be possible to have an implementation where the alignment requirement for some structures containing primitives or arrays thereof might be coarser than the alignment requirement of the largest primitive therein.  If, for example, a Z80 compiler were to require that eight-byte structures be eight-byte aligned, and all pointers be two-byte aligned, the code for `someStruct->offset7=3;` could be `ld hl,(someStruct) / ld a,(hl) / add a,#7 / ld e,a / inc l / ld d,(hl) / ld a,#3 / ld (de),a`.  Much faster than if the compiled code had to accommodate page crossings.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I don't know of any Z80 compilers that actually did such a thing, but compilers that did could offer much better performance on programs they were compatible with than compilers that allow objects to be arbitrarily placed.

Comment: @Raffzahn > "nothing prevents a 32 bit ISA to be implemented using 8 bit (or serial) access" - you mean like the 68008?

Comment: @Greenaum That would be a valid example. As would be a 68030 (0r 80486) running from an 8 bit bus :))

Comment: The 486 could run on an 8-bit bus!?!? I've never, ever heard of that! Searching for it has led me to some maniac putting a 486 on an S-100 card! But there's a problem cos it can only (only!) throttle down to 8MHz. Perhaps one of the laptop versions was fully static down to zero? He mentions though having to use all 32 data lines so it's not making a lot of sense, is there some site that explains this 8-bit mode? And more importantly, WHY!? Why would Intel think anyone would run an 8-bit bus on their then-flagship CPU?

Comment: There are modern CPUs that require stricter alignment: x86-32 with SSE registers (32-bit CPU, 128-bit memory alignment required); TriCore (32-bit CPU; some operations require 128-bit or even 512-bit alignment); some PowerPC CPUs (32- or 64-bit CPU; `stmw` instruction may require up to 512-bit alignment depending on the arguments).

Comment: You also have to see that there are C compilers that don't store the complete address in a pointer but only an offset relative to the data segment. Using such a compiler, `sizeof(void *)` might be 2 (16 bits) on a 64-bit machine. If you do that on a MIPS processor, the alignment of `uint32_t` is 4 bytes (32 bits) while both `sizeof(uint16_t)` and `sizeof(void *)` is only 2 bytes (16 bits).

Comment: " I assume the pointer-sized integers have the same width as the machine word". Well, if you want to port to the 68000, this is an incorrect assumption, since the machine word is 16 bits and an address is 24 bits but requires 32 bits of storage. Aligment requirements are the same - both need an even address.

Comment: JeremyP , also, if you're Apple 30-odd years ago, remember not to use those upper 8 bits to store anything! It's NOT a clever hack, it's a legendary FUBAR that's gonna gum up the works for the next 10 or 15 years! They even have to invent "32-bit clean" as a certification for software that ISN'T SNAFU'd with those upper bits!

Just a tip for any Apple system guys back in the 1980s. No need to thank me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are there pre-32-bit era ISAs with

That's a bit fuzzy, as 32 bit ISAs are older than most 8 or 16 bit ISAs, not to mention many that are smaller or larger than 32 bit.

The text makes it sound you're focusing on rather recent microprocessor architectures (mainly x86, maybe as well ARM, MIPS, etc.). Thus it would be more helpful if you could confine the kind of machines/time frame you'll want to port that software to.

> alignment requirements stricter than machine words?

That's a clear **No**. There are no stricter requirements than the ISA word.

A machine word is by definition the basic access unit which an ISA is constructed around. Thus, in (somewhat) modern 32-bit architectures it's perfectly safe to assume 32-bit alignment.

But there are a few caveats:

- A machine word may be more or less than 32 bits
- It might not be an exact multiple or divisor of 32
- There are 18, 24, 36 and 72 bit architectures (and anything you might imagine in between)

> The only assumption I've made about the environment, is that bytes are exactly 8 bits.

That's valid nowadays with byte-addressable ISAs being canon. But historically

- A byte may or may not have 8 bit.
- Byte sizes from 6 to 9 have been commonly used.
- The smallest accessible unit may be larger than a byte.

> I assume the pointer-sized integers have the same width as the machine word

Again, that's valid with most of today's machines, but historically the same goes as with bytes:

- A memory pointer may be smaller than a machine word
- A memory pointer may be wider than a machine word.

> To limit scope creep, let's limit to ones that're supported as targets by a C compiler.

Not really helping, as C is available for almost every machine out there, even really odd ones.

---

Now, with the TL;DR; added, the question almost answers itself:

**No, there are not**.

By assumption of SIP16/ILP32/LP64/etc. it already determines that the software will only care for exactly this setup - or, as alternative interpretation, not care at all what it's really compiled to.

This hits the age-old duality of fine/absolute control vs. perfect portability and as we all know: *It's impossible to get both.*

---

Last but not least, there may be another word size you may want to care about, the **memory word** and in extension thereof a **cache line**. Knowledge of both may bring huge benefit to performance when used accordingly.

A CPU may have a smaller or wider memory word than its machine word.

If the machine word is wider than its memory word, any misalignment that is still aligned to memory word will not result in a penalty. For example an 80386 has a 32-bit machine word but a 16-bit memory word. Performance-wise there is no difference if a 32-bit word is 16-bit or 32-bit aligned.

It gets a bit more complicated when a memory word is wider than a machine word (and used data types). For example a Pentium has a 64-bit memory word (*1). Thus any 32-bit alignment (for 32-bit values) is equally fine when looking at a single data item, as it can be fetched by a single memory access.

But as soon as this is about either a series of words or a structure longer than a single ISA word, aligning this structure to the memory word will result in notably higher performance. This is due to the first memory access fetching two words at once, thus having the second ready without need for another (slower) memory access.

This gets even more notable when caches are involved, as they are usually not organized as words but multiples thereof, called *cache lines*. For example, the aforementioned Pentium has a 256-bit (32-byte) cache line. That is, every memory access will (if possible) fetch 32 bytes at once, whenever a byte within is needed. As a result, it's favorable to have structures aligned to 32-byte borders, making the CPU loading the first 8 words in a single fetch, resulting in consecutive operations on multiple words within notably faster.

More modern CPUs extend this to 512-bit (64-byte) lines. Though it's not rally a new development. In the 1970s mainframes used (core!) memory words of 2, 4 or 8 ISA words to improve access speed - not to mention semiconductor cache which became standard at the time.

Bottom line, while alignment below ISA word size may be well known as cause of notable penalty, this is also true for alignment below memory word and cache line sizes.

---

*1 - Well, it can run on any memory size from 8 to 64 bit, but I guess it's safe to assume the 64 is the overwhelming default.

Comment: "Valid nowadays with byte addressable ISA being canon". DSPs and similar special purpose CPUs often have more than 8 bit in a byte even today.  Probably not something to worry about if you're writing general purpose code, but might be.

Comment: Wow, that's a good lengthy read. But some points didn't hit the mark, so I updated my question with a TL;DR. Would you consider updating your answer as well?

Comment: @DannyNiu The answer will be still the same: **No, there are not**. Maybe more important, by reducing it to SIP16/ILP32/LP64/etc. you already made the question itself superfluous, as the assumption of any of them already states that the software does not care about how it's 'really' organized on a level below that. It's the old question of fine/absolute control vs. perfect portability. It's impossible to get both. (let me ad this to the question)

Comment: "A machine word is by definition the basic access unit which an ISA is constructed around." If you define "machine word" as "number of bits read at once from memory" (which is what matters for alignment), then they are quite a few architectures that pack multiple "ISA words" into a "machine word" (for example, a Cray-1 has a 64-bit MSW, but a 16-bit ISA). Often that's because a machine word represents a float, and an "ISA word" is less bits.

Comment: I've seen a modern MCU (i.MX RT 1060), which, while being a 32-bit Cortex-M, has memories that had all three of 16, 32 and 64 bus widths. Most, but not all, cached.

Comment: @dirkt What you're pointing to is a memory word - the number of bits used at the memory interface - as mentioned in detail after the divider :)

Comment: I'd like to challenge 'machine word' definition too. What is machine word in a contemporary x86 machine? Data width to the external memory? Cache line size? Register (which one? xmm? ymm? zmm?) size? Address size?

Comment: Then OP's and your definition of "machine word" don't match - the OP is concerned about the alignment, not about ISA. So maybe the OP should clarify what he means by "machine word" (and I'd assume he means what you call a "memory word").

Comment: @dirkt I don't think so, as his definition is based on a languages (C in this case) POV, which most clearly is not a memory word. After all, the very definition of a basic word size for an ISA is to be independent of implementation specific details. It's what IBM did when introducing the /360. From the start IBM ofered models with 16, 32 and 64 bit memory interfaces (later models up to 512), all adhering to the same 32 bit ISA.

Comment: @lvd: Yeah, modern x86 microarchitectures are not a word-oriented at all; "machine word" is a concept that doesn't really apply.  They have fully efficient unaligned (and byte) loads / stores at any misalignment as long as it doesn't cross a cache-line boundary.  I argued this point in [an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229585/are-machine-code-instructions-fetched-in-little-endian-4-byte-words-on-an-intel/68229991#68229991).  The existence of SIMD and efficient load-pair / store-pair on ISAs like modern ARM64 also muddy the waters there.

Comment: @lvd: as far as ABIs for modern ISAs, different types can have different alignment requirements.  e.g. `alignof(uint16_t) == 2` while `alignof(uint64_t) == 8` on most modern 64-bit ABIs, although i386 System V only has `alignof(uint64_t) == 4`.  Alignment is always going to be some power of 2, and you could certainly imagine an ABI where `struct { int a[4]; };` gets alignof() == 16` to allow efficient copying, instead of the `4` it inherits from the alignment of its members; being constructed around units of the machine word and wider doesn't rule that out.  Real-world ABIs don't, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not sure if that invalidates the basic definition. What you're describing is simply that there are implementations that throw hardware at the issue of misalignment, _reducing_ the impact - but never eliminating.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Within a single cache line, there is literally zero difference between `mov rax, [rdi+8]` and `mov rax, [rdi+9]`.  Exact same load-use latency and throughput; [microbenchmarks have verified this in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70431834/224132), and see [byte store throughput vs. non-x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528/224132).  (Perhaps load-use latency could have been lower for aligned operands if Intel/AMD didn't include all the logic to handle misalignment efficiently, but probably the critical path is the TLB check anyway.)

Comment: The simplest way to avoid crossing cache-line boundaries is to give most types natural alignment; that *is* still slower, especially for page splits.  But really the unit of access that matters is the cache line, not anything you could sensibly call a machine word.  (That's the point I'm debating, not that alignment matters and is useful.)

Answer (score 7):

There are many machines which forbade data structures from crossing certain power-of-two boundaries that were larger than a word.  If one wants to use a single 16K DMA buffer to feed audio to a DOS-era SoundBlaster(R) or compatible board, for example, the buffer would be forbidden from straddling a 64K boundary.  While one could use an address whose starting offset within the 64K block boundary was anywhere between 0 and 49152, forcing an address to be a multiple of 16384 bytes would naturally take care of that requirement.

Additionally, it was and remains common for systems to set the location of a data structure by setting the high order address bits, while the low-order address bits of the data structure are fixed.  The Z80 interrupt vector table, for example, must always start on a multiple-of-256 boundary, and 8086 memory segment start addresses are required to be multiples of 16 bytes.

Finally, while this is more of a software issue than a hardware one, on many 8-bit architectures it will be much easier to make a program relocatable on arbitrary multiple-of-256 boundaries than to allow arbitrary relocation anywhere, especially if the program does any tricky program-address calculations or--for the 6502--has any time-critical loops.

Comment: Technically, it's not forbidden, it is possible but might make little sense. The DMA hardware just made to operate within 64k pages as the DMA controller works with 16-bit addresses and there is a separate latch which provides the necessary upper bits for each DMA channel which the DMA controller is unaware of. So you can make a 32k transfer from a 48k offset within a 64k page, it will just transfer 16k from top of the 64k page and wrap around and transfer 16k from the bottom of the 64k page.

Comment: @Justme: If one were to allocate an entire 64K block of memory, one could write code that exploits the fact that DMA accesses wrap at 64K boundaries, but the buffer would still not cross the boundary between two pages.  When I say DMA transfers that cross block boundaries are forbidden, what I mean is that there is no way to request such a transfer *that would actually result in such a transfer being performed*.

Comment: OK, but is the OP going to be encrypting such things.  I was going to point out that VAX, a 32-bit machine, has some structures which demand 8-byte alignment (self-relative queue headers for one).  But these are not types in C, and in any case I think encryption of them unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

From experience with working with several C compilers on 8-bit and 16-bit machines in the 1980s:

- On 8080, Z80, and the like, nobody ever put padding into data structures. There was no performance gain there, and you could not afford to waste memory.  so everything was byte-aligned.
- Early C compilers for MS-DOS used byte alignment, because the original PC and many of the compatibles only had byte-wide memory.
- The hardware gradually changed, but different compilers changed at different times. By the time 32-bit DOS extenders became widely used in the late eighties, natural alignment of 32-bit ints and pointers was normal, for the performance gains and the larger amounts of available memory. That posed major problems for a product I worked on, whose save file format assumed there was no padding.
- In the mid-1990s, several customers of the product I now work on tried using the Visual C++ compiler option /Zp, which controls structure packing, apparently in the hope of saving memory. Since the API they were calling passes structs by value, they got plenty of crashes, and we warned against this in the documentation.

Comment: My recollection is that compilers for the 8088/8086 almost always had a compiler option to either force 16-bit alignment or not.  Were there any that didn't?

Comment: @supercat: Sorry, don't know.